# Why is my bitmap drawing function plotting at an offset from the position I give it? (C VGA Mode 12h)

Tags: c, bitmap, vga

Hello I´m working on creating a bitmap drawing function on C using VGA in mode 12h using DOSBOX to run the program. I´m getting the image on the screen, but the start of the image is being drawn on the middle on the screen instead of (0,0). Can anyone tell me why I´m getting this behavior?

My plot_pixel function works fine. I´m able to draw lines and plot pixels on the screen without getting the weird offset I´m getting now.

This shows the problem.

**Original Image:**
[image]

**Result:**
[image]

And this is my code:

**Load BMP:**

```
/**************************************************************************
 *  load_bmp                                                              *
 *    Loads a bitmap file into memory.                                    *
 **************************************************************************/

void load_bmp(char *file, BITMAP *b){

    FILE *fp;
    long index;
    byte a;
    word num_colors;
    int x;
    //SetGfxMode(0x3);

    /*Opening file */
    if((fp = fopen(file,"rb")) == NULL){

        printf("Error al abrir el archivo %s.\n",file);
        exit(1);
    }

    /*Validating if the image is a valid bitmap*/
    if(fgetc(fp) != 'B' || fgetc(fp) != 'M'){

        fclose(fp);
        printf("%s is not a bitmap file. \n", file);
        exit(1);

    }


    /*Height and width of the image
    */
    fskip(fp,16);
    fread(&b->width, sizeof(word),1 , fp);
    fskip(fp,2);
    fread(&b->height, sizeof(word),1,fp);
    fskip(fp,22);
    fread(&num_colors,sizeof(word),1,fp);
    fskip(fp,6);

    /* We are loading a 16 color image */
    if(num_colors ==0) num_colors = 16;


    /*Intentamos alojar memoria para la data del bitmap*/
    if((b->data = (byte *) malloc((b->width*b->height))) == NULL)
    {
        fclose(fp);
        printf("Error allocating memory for file %s.\n",file);
        exit(1);

    }

    /*Reading pallete info*/
    for(index=0;index<num_colors;index++){
        b->pallete[(int)(index*3+2)] = fgetc(fp) >> 2;
        b->pallete[(int)(index*3+1)] = fgetc(fp) >> 2;
        b->pallete[(int)(index*3+0)] = fgetc(fp) >> 2;
        //fskip(fp,240);
        x = fgetc(fp);

    }


    /* Leyendo el bitmap*/
    for(index=(b->height-1)*b->width;index>=0;index-=b->width){
        for(x=0;x<b->width;x++){
          b->data[index+x]=(byte)fgetc(fp);
        }
    }
    fclose(fp);


}
```

**Draw bitmap:**

```
/**************************************************************************
 *  draw_transparent_bitmap                                               *
 *    Draws a transparent bitmap.                                         *
 **************************************************************************/

void draw_transparent_bitmap(BITMAP *bmp,int x,int y)
{
  int i,j;
  unsigned long bitmap_offset = 0;
  byte data;
    copyMemory(double_buffer,VGA);

    printf("sum");
    getch();
  for(j=0;j<bmp->height;j++)
  {
    for(i=0;i<bmp->width;i++)
    {
      data = bmp->data[bitmap_offset];
      //if (data) double_buffer[screen_offset+x+i] = data;
      if(data) plot_pixel(x+i,y+j,data);
      bitmap_offset++;
    }
  }
}
```

**Set Pallete**

```
void set_pallete(byte *pallete){
    int i;
    outp(PALETTE_INDEX,0);
    for(i=0;i<16*3;i++){
        outp(PALETTE_DATA,pallete[i]);
    }
}
```

**Main:**

```
typedef struct

{
    word width;
    word height;
    byte pallete[256*3];
    byte *data;


} BITMAP;
BITMAP fondo_inicio;


load_bmp("home16.bmp",&fondo_inicio);
set_pallete(fondo_inicio.pallete);
draw_transparent_bitmap(&fondo_inicio,0,0);
```

Comment: A *minimal* example is always better...

Comment: I can't see what is wrong, but be aware that `bitmap_offset++;` won't work when moving to the next row when the image width is not a multiple of 4. The bitmap row storage is always a multiple of 4 bytes.

Comment: @WeatherVane Thanks for your comment. Yes, right now the image is the entire screen (e.g 640*480) so I don´t get those kinds of problems.

Comment: I see you have an answer now, but: I suspect the error follows the  comment `/* Leyendo el bitmap*/`. First, try to read it simply, without any image inversion. Next, you might have an alignment issue with data, as it also seems your palette does not match the original. So you might not be reading the bitmap data from the right offset in the file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not persuaded you're loading the BMP correctly. Per Wikipedia, which hopefully managed to get this right as a rare all-but-objective fact, your code, after you've checked for 'BM', assuming `fskip` is some sort of spin on `fseek`, takes these steps:

- skip the 4 bytes telling you BMP size;
- skip the 4 reserved bytes;
- skip the 4 bytes telling you where you should load pixel data from (which you really should consume and obey);
- assume you're getting a Windows 3.1 secondary header and skip the 4 bytes tell you its length (you shouldn't);
- read the lower two bytes of width;
- skip the upper two bytes of width;
- read the lower two bytes of height;
- skip the upper two bytes of height;
- skip: number of colour planes (+ 2 bytes), bits per pixel (+ 2 bytes), compression method (+ 4 = 10), image size (+ 4 = 14), horizontal density (+ 4 = 18), vertical density (+4 = 22);
- read first two bytes of colour palette size;
- skip next two bytes of colour palette size;
- skip number of important colours;
- assume the headers have then ended (but you should instead have read the header size and skipped appropriate here);
- reads an RGBA palette, assuming it knows the image to be 16-colour, discarding the alpha and mapping from 8 bits-per-channel to VGA-style 6 bits;
- assume the image data comes straight after the palette (you shouldn't, you should have read its file offset earlier);
- read one byte per pixel of image data. Even though you've assumed 4 bits per pixel for reading the palette.

Likely your BMP file isn't 4-bit if reading a whole byte per pixel is providing the correct width of image. That means your assumptions about header size are definitely wrong. Almost certainly what you have stored as the image data is a chunk of header and then the image. Start by not skipping the header entry that tells you where image data begins — read it and use it. Otherwise if your `plot_pixel` automatically maps eight bits to four then it's not a big problem if you're loading a 256-colour image and assuming that only the lowest sixteen colours are used, assuming that holds true of your source imagery and storage space isn't a concern.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Tommy. You are right, the load bitmap function I created assumes a 256- color image. That´s why the image is getting loaded entirely. I need to work on making the function able to load 16 color images. Do you think that might be affecting the weird offset of the drawing?

Comment: I think you should, at the very least, read those 4 bytes at decimal offset 10 — so as a modification of your existing code, check the 'BM' then skip 8, then read the four-byte offset, then skip 4, to replace your current skip of 16 — and seek to that before starting to read image data. You'll still be ignoring a bunch of things that rigorous code would worry about but that's not the point and probably it'll solve your problem in one fell swoop.

Comment: Thank you very much. You were right. I read the the bytes you told, fskipped and now the image displays perfectly. I´ll keep working now with the pallete, which may have similar problems. Thanks again!